# Ionic 4 Angular Getting response from API doesn't working. By postman I get correct

Tags: angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic4

Ionic v4

Items controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcka7.jpg)

Response in DevTools -> in "Data" I always get data from database - in web application everything works correctly
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmR7k.jpg)

Response from Postman:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5hM5.jpg)

Please could anyone explain me what is bad i'm my code?

Ionic info: 
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.8.0 (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.11.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.1.4
   @angular/cli                  : 7.1.4
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.2

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.3.2, (and 5 other plugins)

System:

NodeJS : v8.11.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 10

EDIT: New response after @N. Tasikj comment:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdXS9.jpg)

EDIT2: After change Content-Type application/json

Get item-front:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzQdR.jpg)

Get item-backend:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbACd.jpg)

login backend: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5svd0.jpg)

Comment: In response from devtools we can see a html code instead of json data

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

so, if you want your response to be JSON change header - Content Type in your controller. Change it with

> application/json

Comment: Thanks, but this does not fixed problem. Now I get 200 in error without data from database. - I added new image after your suggestion

Comment: But you tried this for login, change it in items controller, not in login. Also this is probably server-side problem where json response is not supported. You need to set json response there and then call api with app/json content type.

Comment: The same happens with login and items. I added a screenshot from the items and added the code from the getItem from the backend and also from / login

Comment: And even the shot does not reach the backend because I do not stop at my breakppoint in intellij idea